# SQLAlchemy query to PostgreSQL with arbitrary filled form's fields

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have flask app with HTML page and html form for searching students in database with fields like:
group_id, first_name, last_name.

In flask app:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    args = request.args
    f_name = args.get('first_name')
    l_name = args.get('last_name')
    group_id = args.get('group_id')

stmt = select(Student).where(Student.group_id == group_id,
                             Student.first_name == first_name,
                             Student.l_name = last_name)
    result = db.session.execute(stmt)
```

How can I send a query to PostreSQL to search students if **not all form fields** required to be filled to search by any?
This code doesn't work, as some args can be None

Thanks in advance

Comment: First create dictionary of filters and then pass it in where condition .

Comment: Many thanks! I studied what is dictionary of filters and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
    filters = {'first_name': args.get('first_name'),
               'last_name': args.get('last_name'),
               'group_id': args.get('group_id')
              }
    for k in list(filters.keys()):
        if filters[k] == '':
            del filters[k]

    query = db.session.query(Student).filter_by(**filters)
```